# Compute square distances from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having a brain lapse, but I just can't get this to work. I have an array of distances:

```
import numpy as np
zvals = np.linspace(-5,5,10)
d = np.array([(0,0,z) for z in zvals])
```

I want to compute the square distance of the points in the array. The non-numpy way to make this work is:

```
d2 = np.array([np.dot(d[i,:],d[i,:]) for i in range(d.shape[0])])
```

However, I **know** that there must be some way to do this with just a single call to dot, right? That being said, neither

```
d2 = np.dot(d,d.T)
```

or

```
d2 = np.dot(d.T,d)
```

give what I want. I'm being stupid, I realize, but please enlighten me here. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm.np.diag(np.dot(d,d.T)) appears to work. Is there a better way??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit: As of NumPy 1.9, it appears inner1d may be faster. (Thanks to Nuno Aniceto for pointing this out):

```
In [9]:  %timeit -n 1000000 inner1d(d,d)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.39 µs per loop

In [14]: %timeit -n 1000000 einsum('ij,ij -> i', d, d)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.8 µs per loop
```

PS. Always test benchmarks for yourself on inputs similar to your intended use case. Results may vary for a variety of reasons, such as size of input, hardware, OS, Python version, NumPy version, compiler, and libraries (e.g. ATLAS, MKL, BLAS).

---

If you have NumPy version 1.6 or better, you could use [np.einsum](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
In [40]: %timeit np.einsum('ij,ij -> i', d, d)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.79 us per loop
```

---

```
In [46]: from numpy.core.umath_tests import inner1d

In [48]: %timeit inner1d(d, d)
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.97 us per loop
```

---

```
In [44]: %timeit np.sum(d*d, axis=1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.39 us per loop
```

---

```
In [41]: %timeit np.diag(np.dot(d,d.T)) 
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.2 us per loop
```

---

```
In [42]: %timeit np.array([np.dot(d[i,:],d[i,:]) for i in range(d.shape[0])])
10000 loops, best of 3: 26.1 us per loop
```

Comment: Wow. I hadn't heard of einsum before. Thanks.

Comment: `np.einsum` always gets +1! Can you add timings against `inner1d`? I can't time it right now, but I think it may be a serious contender.

Comment: @Jaime: Thanks, Jaime. That's a new one for me.

Comment: @unutbu nice solution. I understand why it is faster than `diag(dot(d,d.T))` (because that does unnecessary calculations), but can you explain why it is much faster than `sum(d**2)`?

Comment: @Bitwise: [np.sum](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L1472) is partially written in Python. [np.einsum](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/einsum.c.src) in written in C. `np.sum(d*d)` requires at least two Python function calls (`np.sum` and `d.__mul__`). `np.einsum` uses just one. Moreover, `np.einsum` is especially designed for taking a sum of products. I'm guessing `np.einsum` does not allocate a shape `(n,3)` intermediate array (as `d*d` requires); rather, it can compute the length `n` 1D result directly.

Comment: @unutbu Thanks for updating this. Had no idea this would be such an interesting thread. Thanks to all who answered.

Comment: you should use the same number of loops in each test. anyway on my laptop (x64) np.einsum performs worse than inner1d (did several tests) !

%timeit -n 1000000 np.einsum('ij,ij -> i', d, d)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 4.23 µs per loop

%timeit -n 1000000 inner1d(d,d)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 4 µs per loop

Answer (score 4):

Dot product functions are very fast, and for really simple stuff may even beat `np.einsum` (which is a terrific function you should definitely learn to use). Numpy has a hidden little gem, `inner1d`, which does the dot product, with broadcasting, over the last dimensions of its arguments. You can use it as follows:

```
from numpy.core.umath_tests import inner1d
inner1d(a, a)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a neat way to slot the normal dot product method into a larger array. Instead, I usually do:

```
d2 = n.sum(d*d,axis=1)
```

The d*d is of course the standard dot product operation since it's just elementwise multiplication of all entries in the array. The `axis=1` argument sums along the second axis (horizontally, as the array is printed), which is the second part of the dot product operation.

Edit: Also, ignoring the general undesirability of the method, your line

```
d2 = np.array([np.dot(d[i,:],d[i,:]) for i in range(d.shape[0])])
```

can be simply

```
d2 = np.array([np.dot(row,row) for row in d])
```

as numpy arrays return rows rather than individual matrix entries when using the 'for in array' syntax.

Comment: Nice! I misspoke when I said that I wanted np.dot to do this. I just want a pure numpy solution, which is what you've provided. Thanks!

Comment: unutbu's answers are an even better (and faster!) example of properly using numpy syntax, I just checked and it looks like the np.sum method is a little slower than np.diag one and much slower than einsum.

Comment: Thanks for checking up on this!