# Contour plotting orbitals in pyquante2 using matplotlib

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I'm currently writing line and contour plotting functions for my [PyQuante](https://github.com/rpmuller/pyquante2) quantum chemistry package using matplotlib. I have some great functions that evaluate basis sets along a (npts,3) array of points, e.g.

```
from somewhere import basisset, line
bfs = basisset(h2) # Generate a basis set
points = line((0,0,-5),(0,0,5)) # Create a line in 3d space
bfmesh = bfs.mesh(points)
for i in range(bfmesh.shape[1]):
    plot(bfmesh[:,i])
```

This is fast because it evaluates all of the basis functions at once, and I got some great help from stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396164/numpythonic-way-to-make-3d-meshes-for-line-plotting) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391052/compute-square-distances-from-numpy-array) to make them extra-nice.

I would now like to update this to do contour plotting as well. The slow way I've done this in the past is to create two one-d vectors using linspace(), mesh these into a 2D grid using meshgrid(), and then iterating over all xyz points and evaluating each one:

```
f = np.empty((50,50),dtype=float)
xvals = np.linspace(0,10)
yvals = np.linspace(0,20)
z = 0
for x in xvals:
    for y in yvals:
        f = bf(x,y,z)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(xvals,yvals)
contourplot(X,Y,f)
```

(this isn't real code -- may have done something dumb)

What I would like to do is to generate the mesh in more or less the same way I do in the contour plot example, "unravel" it to a (npts,3) list of points, evaluate the basis functions using my new fast routines, then "re-ravel" it back to X,Y matrices for plotting with contourplot.

The problem is that I don't have anything that I can simply call .ravel() on: I either have 1d meshes of xvals and yvals, the 2D versions X,Y, and the single z value.

Can anyone think of a nice, pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can express `f` as a function of `X` and `Y`, you could avoid the Python `for-loop`s this way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def bf(x, y):
    return np.sin(np.sqrt(x**2+y**2))

xvals = np.linspace(0,10)
yvals = np.linspace(0,20)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xvals,yvals)
f = bf(X,Y)
plt.contour(X,Y,f)
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the way to go. I was hoping I could reuse some of the stuff you've helped me make so fast, though, so I don't have several different ways to evaluate basis functions on meshes. Thanks!

Comment: I ended up doing this. In the end, I only had two routines to write: one that is a routine to evaluate a basis function on x,y,z points, that can pass in the meshgrid-ed 2d arrays as well, and another that evaluates the function on an nx3 grid. Thanks again for the help.